# Dividing Math with C#

Tags: c#, math, double

This has a potentially simple answer but I can't figure it out -

```
double Result = 1 / 12;
```

returns 0, while

```
double Result2 = 24 / 12;
```

return 2

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: use decimal instead of double? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? Perfectly valid question for someone new or not-so-experienced to programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
double Result = 1 / (double)12;
```

or this:

```
double Result = 1 / 12D;
```

In C# (and also in a lot of other languages), integer division returns an integer. By casting one of the operands to `double` or explicitly declaring a literal `double` you can force the division expression to return a `double` and not truncate after the decimal place.

Comment: Just to add, the integer division will truncate the decimal value, not round to the nearest value.  So `5/3 = 1` and `-5/3 = -1` and not 2 or -2 as expected from normal rounding.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: that's what I said.  I just figured it'd be worthwhile for William to know.

Answer (score 3):

it is doing integer math because the numbers on the right are evaluated as integers.

try `1.0/12`;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast your values

```
double Result = (double)1 / (double)12
```

has something to do with integer based math always returns an integer.....

Comment: Casting only one of them will also do.

Answer (score 0):

this will work too

```
Decimal.Divide(1, 12)
```

It has a result with higher precision, but a smaller range.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `1` and `12` are integers (of type `int`, not `double`). This means the values ignore anything past the decimal point. When you divide 1 by 12, you get 0.083. Since anything past the decimal point is truncated for `int`, you are left with `0`.

To get expected results, one of your operands needs to be of type `double`. You can do this by changing `1` to `1.0` or 12 to `12.0` (or both, as long as at least one of the operands is a `double`).